# Django - how to send "POST" information from one view to another

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-registration, http-redirect, django-login

I have a registration form and if the registration form is filled in correctly and is valid, I want to automatically log the user in. The login view is at the URL

```
/login/
```

and this is the login view which that URL is linked to (it's the generic login view):

```
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
      redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
      authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
      current_app=None, extra_context=None):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = authentication_form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Ensure the user-originating redirection url is safe.
            if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
                redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

            # Okay, security check complete. Log the user in.
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())

            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)

else:
    form = authentication_form(request)

request.session.set_test_cookie()

current_site = get_current_site(request)

context = {
    'form': form,
    redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
    'site': current_site,
    'site_name': current_site.name,
}
if extra_context is not None:
    context.update(extra_context)
return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                        current_app=current_app)
```

Now, the view which handles registration is:

```
def registrationView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(
        username=form.clean_data['username'],
        password=form.clean_data['password1'],
        email=form.clean_data['email']
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

Now, when I redirect to

```
/login/
```

in the registration view, is it possible for me to send the username and password as "POST" information so that when it reaches the login view

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

evaluates to true?

Comment: Why would you want to do that thing?

Comment: @geekazoid because I want to use the login view to log the user in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that, instead of trying to do such magic, you should set the current user to your session.

```
def registrationView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(
        username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
        password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
        email=form.cleaned_data['email']
        )
        login(request, user) 

        return HttpResponseRedirect('...')
```

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login

Comment: hm, makes sense. When I use your code, it gives an error saying "'RegistrationForm' object has no attribute 'clean_data'" and traces back to the line "username=form.clean_data['username']," in the registrationView.. any idea why?

Comment: [cleaned_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data)

Comment: @sk1p yea just noticed that, thanks, solved the problem.

Comment: @user2719875 did you modify your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting? Does it still contain the `auth` context processor? Did you try to put `{{ user }}` or `{{ user.username }}` into your template?